# Nested Routing In React Router Dom issues

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using the examples from https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/nesting but I am creating it as a separate component. I have Home and Topics and Errorpage components. It keeps routing to the error page when I clicked on the Foo, Bar or Baz and I couldn't get the route param value to display. Is there something I have missed? Thanks a lot and in advance. This is how it looks like;

```
//App.js

import React from 'react'
import style from './App.module.css';
import {Switch, Route, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './components/Home'
import Error from './components/Errorpage'
import Topics from './components/Topics'

const App = () => {
 return (
    <div className={style.App}>
      <NavLink exact to="/" activeStyle={{fontWeight:'bold',color:'blue'}}>Home</NavLink>
      <NavLink exact to="/topics" activeStyle={{fontWeight:'bold',color:'blue'}}>More Topics</NavLink>

      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
        <Route exact path="/topics" component={Topics} /> 
        <Route component={Error} />
      </Switch>    
    </div>
  )
}

export default App

//Home.js

import React,{useState} from 'react'
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

const Home = () => {
  
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Home Page</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home

//Errorpage.js

import React from 'react'

const Errorpage = props => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1 style={{color:'red'}}>Opps. Sorry, page not found!</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Errorpage

//Topics.js

import React from 'react'
import {Switch,Route,Link,useParams,useRouteMatch} from "react-router-dom"

const Topics = props => {
    let { path, url } = useRouteMatch();
    return (
        <div>
         <h2>Topics</h2>
          <ul style={{listStyleType:'none'}}>
            <li>
              <Link to={`${url}/foo`}>Foo</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to={`${url}/bar`}>Bar</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to={`${url}/baz`}>Baz</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path={path}>
          <h3>Please select a topic.</h3>
        </Route>
        <Route path={`${path}/:topicId`}>
          <Topic />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
        </div>
    )
}

function Topic() {
  let { topicId } = useParams();
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>{topicId}</h3>
    </div>
  );
}


export default Topics
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

Yes, you've missed a small, but very important detail. The `exact` prop matches defined paths exactly. As soon as you hit a nested sub-route, you no longer match the root path *exactly*.

## Solution

You can't specify the `exact` prop on routes that contain nested routes. If you take a closer look at *that* demo you'll see the same on their `"/topics"` path.

```
const App = () => {
 return (
    <div className={style.App}>
      <NavLink exact to="/" activeStyle={{fontWeight:'bold',color:'blue'}}>Home</NavLink>
      <NavLink exact to="/topics" activeStyle={{fontWeight:'bold',color:'blue'}}>More Topics</NavLink>

      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
        <Route path="/topics" component={Topics} /> 
        <Route component={Error} />
      </Switch>    
    </div>
  )
}
```